# Access Firestore Database without authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my app, I would like to check if there is a document with the same email before a user signs in (where `'email'` is a field of documents in my `'user_data'` collections)...

I already did the code which does that, but it needs access to my Firestore database even though the user isn't already signed in (and in my Firestore rules I said `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`)

So, how can I change my Firestore rules without allowing `read` to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing your firebase database security rules to the public is not advisable.

But I could understand your situation. I could give you an idea.

This is how I implement it, without changing the security rules.

**WHEN YOU WANT TO CHECK AFTER CLICKING THE BUTTON:**

```
//SIGN UP

try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "USER ENTERED PASSWORD",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
    // Tell User That It already exists!
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

// Or SIGN IN

try {
 UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

**WHEN YOU WANT TO CHECK WHILE TYPING IN EMAIL TEXTFIELD:**

```
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

You could sign in anonymously and read the database! After reading and filtering out log out the user.

Or else if you haven't convinced yet, then here you go,

Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access

Make `read` to public and `write` to auth users.

Hope that suits your case!

Comment: Thank you! I was using both email/password and Google login so I couldn't use the `email already in use` exception, but I solved with the anonymous login one :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

to

```
allow read, write: if true;
```